# Generating binary files with Sitespec fails when a Padrino Rack app

Tags: ruby, rspec, rack, padrino

I am working on a project with Sitespec, which is a static site generator using RSpec and uses any Rack app.  I chose Padrino as a Rack app for Sitespec.

Then, I get the following errors when I do `rspec` at some URLs of `Content-type: image/png` type.

```
Failures:

  1) Sitespec GET public/images/simple-image1.png Generate a static image public/images/simple-image1.png
     Failure/Error: pathname.write(response.body)

     Encoding::UndefinedConversionError:
       "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

`Pathname.write(response.body)` is going to try to convert it to UTF-8.

But when I use Sinatra instead of Padrino, the error does not occur.

I made simple sample projects for comparison:

- Using Padrino https://github.com/Nyoho/sitespec-padrino-sample2
- Using Sinatra https://github.com/Nyoho/simple-sitespec-sinatra-test

**Question**: Why does the Padrino project fail and how do I fix the errors?

By the way, doing monkey patch

```
module Sitespec
  class Artifact
    def generate_file
      pathname.binwrite(response.body)
    end
  end
end
```

eliminates the error. (Replacing `Pathname#write` to `Pathname#binwrite`.)

Comment: The difference is `Encoding.default_internal`. Sinatra does not touch it, Padrino sets it to UTF-8 for no real reason.

Comment: Thank you, ujifgc! Setting `Encoding.default_internal`, it solved!